# Excel - getting the last value when conditions are met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnWTg.png)

Hi I'm trying to get the last value when the following conditions are met.

1. Customer ID = Customer ID
2. Date 1 < Date 2

Value Returned is what I want to have.

I've tried this formula, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
=IF(AND(E2=$A$2:$A$13,B2:B13<F2),$C$2:$C$13)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest date for each customer with this:

```
=MAX(FILTER($B$2:$B$13,($B$2:$B$13<$F2)*($A$2:$A$13=$E2)))
```

And therefore the latest value for that customer on that date with this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INT($A$2:$A$13=$E2),INT($B$2:$B$13=MAX(FILTER($B$2:$B$13,($B$2:$B$13<$F2)*($A$2:$A$13=$E2)))),$C$2:$C$13)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use range of cells in that kind of functions, unless using an array formula.
If you have a new version of Excel with MAXIFS() function, here is another solution:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$13;$B$2:$B$13;"<"&F2;$A$2:$A$13;E2);$B$2:$C$13;2;0)
```

Then drag it to rows 3 and 4.

Explanation:

```
MAXIFS($B$2:$B$13;$B$2:$B$13;"<"&F2;$A$2:$A$13;E2)
```

=> This will look for the last date1 < date2 for the good customer ID.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS(...);$B$2:$C$13;2;0)
```

=> This will look for the value corresponding to the date found in the MAXIFS() return value.
But a problem will appear if 2 customers can have the same date.

If 2 customers can have the same date, then we can use SUMIFS() instead of VLOOKUP():

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$13;$B$2:$B$13;MAXIFS($B$2:$B$13;$B$2:$B$13;"<"&F2;$A$2:$A$13;E2);$A$2:$A$13;E2)
```

=> With the SUMIFS() function we verify to get the value for the good date and for the good customer.

Answer (score 0):

In `G2`, formula copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,C$2:C$13/(A$2:A$13=E2)/(B$2:B$13<F2),1)
```

[image]

Comment: According to what he wrote he wanted, you may want to change `B$2:B$13<=F2)` to `B$2:B$13<F2)`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld, The formula edited in change to "<" in meet with the OP's wanted. Thanks for your comment.